# Programming a queue in C, where did my code go wrong

Tags: c

Trying to write a program in C that creates a queue and allows the user to add values. The queue is set up using an array. Somehow my code isn't working and I was wondering if someone could help me troubleshoot.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CAP 10

//define a struct for our queue
typedef struct _que
{
    int arr[CAP];
    int front;
    int size;
}
que;

void enqueue (que* ptr, int add);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    que q1;
    q1.front = 0;
    q1.size = 0;
    char yn = 'n';
    //while loop for adding elements
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the value you wish to add\n");
        scanf("%d",&i);
        enqueue(&q1, i);
        printf("Would you like to add any more elements?\n");
        scanf("%c",&yn);
    }
    while (yn == 'y' && q1.size <= CAP);
    printf("The current element(s) in the queue are:");
    //TODO: print out elements in the queue
    for(int start = 0; start <= q1.size; start++)
    {
        printf("%d",q1.arr[start]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void enqueue(que* ptr, int add)
{
    ptr->arr[((ptr->front)+(ptr->size))] = add;
    ptr->size += 1;
}
```

The program executes normally up to the part where it prints "would you like to add any more elements", then it just jumps out of the do-while loop and prints the elements in the queue, which also goes wrong as it spits out garbage values like 217836276, probably indicating a memory problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition `start <= q1.size` is wrong and it contains [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). It should be `start < q1.size`.

To avoid reading whitespace character to `yn`, a whitespace should be added before `%c` like `scanf(" %c",&yn);` to have `scanf()` skip whitespace characters.

Also note that the condition `q1.size <= CAP` is also wrong for preventing buffer overrun and it should be `q1.size < CAP`.